# Draw vector graphic

Tags: javascript, vector-graphics, dot

I created a simple graphic with LibreOffice:

[image: simple-drawing-created-by-libreoffice]

The lines are not symmetric.

I am very lazy and a bit autistic. Moving the lines with the mouse does not feel correct for me. I is very unlikely that I will find the matching position for all six lines of this picture.

I would like to code it.

AFAIK there are several ways. You could use [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) or JavaScript.

A pure JS solution would be enough, I don't need to create a SVG/PNG/JPG.

How could this be done with dot or JS?

Comment: I would recommend to use Adobe Illustrator or some substitution app of it and switch the "snap to grid" option on. This way you can always keep everything to inline with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Even in LibreOffice you can use grid. Please see [this answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/21974/i-want-lines-and-text-to-snap-to-vertical-or-horizontal-grid-lines/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library to paint the boxes: http://paperjs.org/